# Jarsigner: "This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated."

Tags: java, applet, jarsigner

I get the following error on a self-signed jar:

```
jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
```

I signed the jar like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\jarsigner" -keystore myKeyStore myJar.jar myAlias
```

My jar has 2 entry points: One for java web start, and one for an applet.

- If I run the jar in a java web start way, it has no incidence.
- But if I run the jar as an applet. I get a strong security warning at some point when I try to access a bitmap resource embeded in the jar.

Using the -verbose and -certs options shows a lot of lines. And I don't understand anything of this. This is the output: [output.txt](http://keyja.com/bin/output.txt)  (part of the 6307 lines reproduced below).

```
s     157850 Tue Nov 08 12:57:44 CET 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

      X.509, O=keyja.com
      [certificate is valid from 17/08/11 17:32 to 24/07/11 17:32]
      [CertPath not validated: null]

      112909 Tue Nov 08 12:57:44 CET 2011 META-INF/KEYJA_CO.SF
        1108 Tue Nov 08 12:57:44 CET 2011 META-INF/KEYJA_CO.RSA
sm       180 Tue Nov 08 12:16:40 CET 2011 com/keyja/client/a/a/a/k.class

      X.509, O=keyja.com
      [certificate is valid from 17/08/11 17:32 to 24/07/11 17:32]
      [CertPath not validated: null]

sm       252 Tue Nov 08 12:16:40 CET 2011 com/keyja/client/a/a/a/r.class
...
(around 6000 lines of other output along the same lines)

  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
```

How to sign the jar file ?

Comment: It makes sense. I included a link to the output.

Comment: *"If I run the jar in a java web start way, it has no incidence."*  What level of security permissions does the JWS launch request?

Comment: If the applet runs sand-boxed as well, why sign the code at all?

Comment: because the applet doesn't work if i don't sign it. it should but it doesn't, for a reason I ignore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4801/discussion-between-andrew-thompson-and-joel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Andrew Thompson. I have unsigned my jar file, and found the bug. It's better unsigned you're right about this, because signing makes no point since I don't need to get out of the sandbox.

For the record, the bug was the use of the jnlp.jar library. In order to make it work, I launched the applet using jnlp/applet code instead of a standard  tag.

Comment: so how did you fix it? a little bit more detail please

Comment: I launched the applet using jnlp/applet code instead of a standard html applet tag. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/embeddingJNLPFileInWebPage.html

Answer (score 1):

Just one line answers you question I guess. And if you look closer you'll see it. Here it is

---

> [certificate is valid from 17/08/11 17:32 to 24/07/11 17:32]

As I may hope, you know that today is not July 24 so you just have to re-sign your app

Comment: If the certificate is no longer valid, then he will have to recreate the certificate to extend the valid time period.

Comment: No, it's 24/07/2111, and it's valid.

Comment: I am just wondering... Is it valid from 17/08/2111 17:32 to 24/07/2111 17:32 ?

Comment: Could you provide the key and the cert validation dates?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.

There is a change in the validation in the new Java 7 and Java 6 versions.
**Bug id is : 6861062   java    classes_security    Disable MD2 in certificate chain validation.**

When signing the Jara file , I had some warning message and when executing the command:
jarsigner MyTools.jar -verify -verbose -certs

I had the message:
      X.509, OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
      [certificate is valid from 29.01.96 01:00 to 02.08.28 01:59]
      [CertPath not validated: Algorithm constraints check failed: **MD2withRSA**]

My solution is :
- use another version of the JDK to sign and JRE Plugin.
- Update your certificate security in order not to use this algorithm.

I hope it will help you.

Regards