# Signing application with Eclipse built in mechanism fails

Tags: android, eclipse, digital-signature

I am using Eclipse to develop android applications and i am trying to sign my application using Eclipse's built in feature for this prupose.

The problem is after the process is finished when i run jarsigner i get this message :

```
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
```

What can be the problem ? Is there an easier way than using Eclipse ?

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049645/jarsigner-this-jar-contains-entries-whose-certificate-chain-is-not-validated

Comment: @Ferdau it's not about eclipse

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the "debug.keystore" at "C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME.android\" folder.

Comment: doesn't work...besides running the export wizard do i need to do something more.. ?

Comment: Did u use any third party Libraries ?

Comment: No i didn't use any libraries